# Getting icon from url and icon from drawable it is taking only from drawable

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-glide

I have added some manually icons to `drawable` which for some manually data it have to take the `drawable` and if a icon is not in `drawable` then take it from the `Glide`.

I tried something like till now but only it is getting the icons from `drawable`.

I want to check if icon exists at `drawable` take from there and if for an url the icon is not in drawable then go at another statement and take it from  `Glide`.

Below is my code.
**The resID is always 0**

```
String imageUrl = BASE_URL + arrayList.get(position).getSearchUrl() + "&size=32";

            int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "drawable",context.getPackageName());
            if (resID == 0) {
                Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + resID);
                viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: Glide" + resID);
                Glide.with(context)
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .apply(requestOptions
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_favicon)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .fitCenter())
                        .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);
            }
```

Comment: check with valid image link for test

Comment: @nima_moradi What do you mean with valid image link the problem it is that it is not going at the else condition.

Comment: you can't add image to res directory at run time

Comment: so why check it at run time for resource availability

Comment: @nima_moradi What do you suggest me to do?
Can you provide an answer or something like this?

Comment: did you debug and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your **`arrayList.get(position).getIcon()`** instead of **`"icon"`** in `context.getResources().getIdentifier()`

Also read how [**`getIdentifier()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) works

> Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry".
>
> **`Returns`** : 
>       int The associated resource identifier. **Returns 0 if no such resource was found. (0 is not a valid resource ID.)**

Try this way

```
    int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable",context.getPackageName()); "drawable",context.getPackageName());
    // if resID == 0 means the icon is not available in drawable folder
    // so it will load icon from url using Glide
    if (resID == 0) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: Glide" + resID);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)
                .apply(requestOptions
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.default_favicon)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                        .fitCenter())
                .into(viewHolder.tvIcon);

    }
    // if resID != 0 means the icon is  available in drawable folder
    // so it will load icon from drawable folder
    else {
        Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: " + resID);
        viewHolder.tvIcon.setImageResource(resID);
    }
```

Comment: It is coming a error `arrayList.get(position).getIcon()` when I write `icon` it compiled but the icons take from that url and in log comes `Log.d("TAG", "onBindViewHolder: Glide" + resID);`

Comment: @Spritzig `It is coming a error arrayList.get(position).getIcon()` what error can u share it wi question

Comment: `Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'int', required: 'java.lang.String' more...`

Comment: Try this `int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position).getIcon()), "drawable",context.getPackageName());`

Comment: it is working man, I have just another little question, I take icons from that url `https://besticon-demo.herokuapp.com/icon?url=` but for some url it is not getting the right url.
Do you know another link which takes the right icon and if the icon it is not more than 16px put the icon into that `R.drawable.default_favicon`

Comment: @Spritzig means

Answer (score 1):

```
int checkExistence = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());

if ( `checkExistence != 0` ) {  // the resouce exists...
result = true;
}
else {  // checkExistence == 0  // the resouce does NOT exist!!
result = false;}
```

you are using`resID == 0` use not equal to zero.`checkExistence != 0`

Comment: I will again explain my problem, I have declared some manually data, they have icons at drawable.
The user can add new data which icon comes from url that user types.
I want for those data which are manually added take the icon from the drawable for those which are not manually declared please take the icon from Glide.